# All My HTTP Imports is showing "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: android, build.gradle

> Here is the Error Import list :-

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; 
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair; 
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity; 
import org.apache.http.client.met
```

> I have Tried changing compileSdkVersion , buildToolsVersion , targetSdkVersion > but nothing seem to be working 
>   Here is my build.gradle :-

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user1.templeapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`enter code here`
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'

}
```

Comment: [Apache HTTP Client Removal from API 23](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) still want to use then add `org.apache.http.legacy` in `build.gradle`

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck with it for a long Time

Comment: its telling unable to find org.apache.http.legacy then i used external jar httpclient-4.5.1 now the error is with BasicNameValuePairs Can anyone Give me A solution